# Where are headers file present in Contiki?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, contiki

I am trying to understand the IPv6-over-BLE UDP-client demo example which is present in `examples/cc26xx/cc26xx-ble-client-demo`, the code has following header files:

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include "contiki-lib.h"
#include "contiki-net.h"

#define DEBUG DEBUG_FULL
#include "net/ip/uip-debug.h"
#include "net/ip/uiplib.h"
#include "net/ipv6/uip-icmp6.h"
```

I just want to know the locations of these header files in the Contiki file system as the code for the main implementation of the BLE connection is under `cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/rf-core/*.[ch]` and `cpu/cc26xx-cc13xx/net/*.[ch]`. I want to understand how the example code can use the methods present in files at different locations.

Comment: What do you like to know, 1. where the header files are, or 2. how the declared methods can be used? The former doesn't help you with the latter. Do you understand the concept of compiling (usage of header files) and linking (usage of libraries)?

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for replying! No I am not clear with the concept of compiling (usage of header files) and linking (usage of libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to understand how an application is build.

1. All executable code is defined in C files and translated into machine code. Having said this, there might be modules written in other languages, the C runtime most probably has some assembler sources. We can call these "translation units" because they are each translated separately on their own.
2. The header files just contain declarations of objects implemented in those translation units. Header files can combine declarations of several units or deliberately leave out some declarations.
3. If you compile one of your own sources which includes a header file there will be no code of the referenced objects in your resulting object file.
4. At the link stage the linker combines all object modules of your program, resolving references between all of them. That means if you have a call in one unit to a method in another module, that call will receive the correct address.
5. There are still unsatisfied references left, in particular those to library methods that were declared in those header files. The linker searches through the default and the explicitely given libraries to look for the methods. If it finds one it will get added to the code and the call will receive its address.

This is it really very short. Please search for a broader description in the web, you'll find a lot of them.

---

**To answer your explicit question: "How can the example code use the methods present in files at different locations?"**

The linker adds the machine code of these methods to the machine code of your modules. The location of their source code is irrelevant. The linker knows the location of the standard libraries. If you use additional libraries, add them (and their path, if needed) to the command line.

If you have any further questions, edit your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below.

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/core

```
"contiki.h"
"contiki-lib.h"
"contiki-net.h"
```

https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ip/uip-debug.h

You can find the header files in the Contiki in the same respective locations.

Answer (score 0):

contiki.h, contiki-lib.h, contiki-net.h: These files are in contiki/core/ folder.

uip-debug.h: contiki/core/net/ip

uiplib.h: contiki/core/net/ip

uip-icmp6.h: contiki/core/net/ipv6/